# Refactor old Web Audio API to new one

Tags: html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm evaluating HTML5 Web Audio API example and trying to get it work. Here is what I'm working [**with**](https://github.com/josdirksen/smartjava/tree/master/webaudio-filters). As far as I got I understood that it's using old API and I need to refactor `function refreshFilterType()` on line ~590. Link - www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio-filters/

According to [`Web Audio BiquadFilterNode`](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-biquadfilternode-interface) I need to rework switch statement and make it 
and to use the new string-based values. (I.e. a value of "3" - the default lowshelf filter - needs to be passed into currentFilterType as "lowshelf"). I've tried to implement new BiquadFilterNode, but still it was unsuccessfully.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have tried to change variables to make it work. My knowledge is very weak. Obviously I played with that function, but all my attempts didn't helped, that's why I'm asking it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just opened a pull request with the necessary fixes.  Or look at https://github.com/cwilso/smartjava.

Answer (score 0):

...and actually, I note the real problem with the code you have is not that it's using numeric values - that's wrong, according to the spec, but it's still supported - it's line 663:

```
filter.type = currentFilterType;
```

currentFilterType is "3" - that is, the STRING "3" - and type now takes a string, so it's not being coerced.  If you changed this line to

```
filter.type = parseInt(currentFilterType);
```

it would actually fix the problem (because filter.type accepts ints, and will coerce them to the appropriate string of "lowpass", etc. - but it doesn't accept the string of a number.)

However, this will fail in the long term, when we remove the deprecated types.